# Apache Drill query on Parquet file not working for timestamp field

Tags: apache-spark-sql, apache-drill

I am trying to query Parquet files which are generated from PySpark job. The data in Timestamp field is coming as hex string. I tried to use CAST function, but it did not work.

Is there any setting which is required to fix this issue.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I got it resolved by adding the following setting to spark session. This would make it compatible with other platforms.

.config("spark.sql.parquet.outputTimestampType","INT96")

Answer (score 0):

If the timestamp is coming back as a hex string, you might try Drill's `CONVERT_FROM()` function. [1](https://drill.apache.org/docs/data-type-conversion/#convert-the-binary-hbase-students-table-to-json-data)

Basically, this can convert a hex string into something else.